# npm: Can I delete empty folders in global node_modules folder?

Tags: npm

I just unistalled some global packages, and afterwards i noticed that there is an empty folder (namely, `@vue`) left in `C:\Users\<myname>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\` (i uninstalled two packages inside, `@vue/cli` and another one, forgot the name).

Can i manually delete such empty folders or do they serve a purpose for npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have uninstalled the package following below instructions, there is no harm if the folder exist or not.
https://docs.npmjs.com/uninstalling-packages-and-dependencies#uninstalling-global-packages

You can ignore or delete the folder, whenever you run a global command npm consider this as uninstalled

Comment: Thanks, and yup, that link was my source of truth. Did `npm uninstall -g <package>` a few times and afterwards `npm cache verify`.